# Распределение логики по моделям. Вызов моделей

Tags: model, php, архитектура, mvc

Итак, имеется простейший блог(а точнее админка блога) с записями, категориями и комментариями. Серверная часть на PHP с использованием паттерна mvc.
Есть 3 модели - модель записи, модель категории и модель комментариев. И соответственно 3 таких же контроллера.

Вопрос следующий:
При входе в управление записями срабатывает контроллер записей. Он создает модель записей. Но при создании записи мне нужно определить ее в какую-то категорию, то есть нужно вывести выпадающий список с перечнем доступных категорий. Но взятие категорий из базы находится в модели категорий, а подгружается то модель записей. Писать ту же функцию (функцию взятия всех категорий) в модели записей - получается плохой код.Подключать и создавать 2 модели - тоже не вариант. Откуда брать категории?

Заранее благодарен за ответы.

Comment: Сразу видно начинающего)) Сам когда-то страдал такой фигней, чтобы максимально все уменьшать и оптимизировать.

На деле вы модели для того и создаете, чтобы они отвечали за ваши данные. Значит без них - никак, иначе смысл их было создавать? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну никто не запрещал в MVC использовать несколько моделей в одном контроллере..
Так что подключай обе.

Comment: У меня роутер грузит за раз 1 модель и 1 контроллер. Не хотелось бы его (процесс роутинга) нагружать так сильно. Да и ради 1 функции грузить целый класс, разве не многовато?

Comment: @snakext, ты еще не видел сколько классов за один проход фреймворки грузят. а в твоем случае это вообще пшик. Тебе нужно грузить один контролер и все. А в нем уже вызывать все необходимые модели. Хоть одну, хоть тысячу. Почитай про паттерн Registry. Очень крутая штука.

Comment: Благодарю за ответы. 
Тогда мне из роутинга загружать только контроллер, а модели подгружать уже в процессе работы, внутри контроллера?

Comment: @snakext, угу и виды тоже

Comment: А еще можно использовать паттерн Singleton в дополнение к Registry

Comment: А почему вы приняли решение грузить модель через роутер? Есть какая-то причина или первое пришедшее в голову решение?